# One DateTime parses fine but the other doesn't?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have an ASP site where I read two dates from two fields.

The dates are generated using JavaScript and one of the two dates I need to read pass but the other doesn't. Even though they are made the exact same way.

So as you see here from my Immediate Window:

```
datepicker_start.Value
"03/10/2016"

datepicker_end.Value
"03/23/2016"
```

The first one parses fine, the second one does not:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(datepicker_start.Value);
DateTime end = DateTime.Parse(datepicker_end.Value);
```

It throws a FormatException on the end date:

```
DateTime.Parse(datepicker_end.Value)
```

threw an exception of type

> System.FormatException: The String wasn't recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.

I cannot understand why this is happening. If you need anything other than what I gave already please let me know as this is truly puzzling.

Comment: its because it's trying to parse dd/MM/yyyy, your second values are in the form MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: When that "03/10/2016" is parsed, is it October or March? And which *should* it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime.Parse` uses standard date and time format of your current culture settings.

*Probably* your culture setting has `dd/MM/yyyy` as a standard format and since there is no 23rd month, your second line throws `FormatException`.

I would suggest to use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact) with a custom format like;

```
DateTime end = DateTime.ParseExact(datepicker_end.Value,
                                   "MM/dd/yyyy",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For example; if you debug your code, your `start` will be 3rd of October, not 10th of March.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Strange, this isn't an issue somewhere else in my code where I do the same. But I guess I will enforce it those places too.

Comment: @Vipar Probably there is no string other than this which has greater than `12` as a month part in your code.